# How to get a particular value from the parsed JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, schema

I am getting the following information from a parsed JSON file. How can I get the value of the [ARRAY] element from the last 'gfs' element,(or whatever it is called)? I have never worked on JSON, What all should I know to do this?

```
  data: [
    {
      url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
      typ: 'base',
      pos: 0,
      gfs: null
    },
    {
      url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
      typ: 'node',
      pos: 1,
      gfs: null
    },
    {
      url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
      typ: 'node',
      pos: 2,
      gfs: null
    },
    {
      url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
      typ: 'boomerang',
      pos: 3,
      gfs: [Array]
    }
  ]
```

[ARRAY] holds some information, I need.

I got this by parsing a JSON string, and printing it to the console.

PS. Only using Javascript.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I have used this to get the result I have showed above.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you are getting an **Array of Object** and you want to access the last element of the array, you can **get last array position by** `array.length - 1`, and access the gfs value. if you want to **check whether gfs value is array** not then you can **check by** `typeof gfs`

```js
var  data= [
        {
          url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
          typ: 'base',
          pos: 0,
          gfs: null
        },
        {
          url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
          typ: 'node',
          pos: 1,
          gfs: null
        },
        {
          url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
          typ: 'node',
          pos: 2,
          gfs: null
        },
        {
          url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
          typ: 'boomerang',
          pos: 3,
          gfs: ['a','b','c']
        }
      ]
    
    // You can access like this
    console.log(data[data.length-1].gfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the array value by `index` so you can use loop to access it by index or you can directly access it using `index` number.

Check out these docs. It will help out to better understand

[Loops_and_iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

[Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

[Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```js
let data =  [
    {
      url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
      typ: 'base',
      pos: 0,
      gfs: null
    },
    {
      url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
      typ: 'node',
      pos: 1,
      gfs: null
    },
    {
      url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
      typ: 'node',
      pos: 2,
      gfs: null
    },
    {
      url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
      typ: 'boomerang',
      pos: 3,
      gfs: [1, 2, 4, 5]
    }
  ];
// by looping 
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {   // iterate on data, for(initilize, condition, increment)
 let item = data[i];                 // access item from data by bracket notation property accessors, pass index number i
 let gfsList = item['gfs']        // grab the gfs object from item by bracket notation property accessors
 if(Array.isArray(gfsList)) {      // check if gfs is array or not
  for(let j = 0; j < gfsList.length; j++) {   //gfs is array so we can iterate again on each item of it
   let gfsItem = gfsList[j];
   console.log(gfsItem);
  }
 }
}
// direct access 
console.log(data[data.length - 1]['gfs'])
```

Comment: I am getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'gfs' of undefined

Comment: @LakshyaWadhwa click on Run code snippet, i think it is working

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() gives JavaScript object. Here it is the Array object, so you can access it by looping the array or specifying the array index directly.

```
var  data = [
        {
          url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
          typ: 'base',
          pos: 0,
          gfs: null
        },
        {
          url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
          typ: 'node',
          pos: 1,
          gfs: null
        },
        {
          url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
          typ: 'node',
          pos: 2,
          gfs: null
        },
        {
          url: 'https://playy-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hidden.mp4',
          typ: 'boomerang',
          pos: 3,
          gfs: [Array]
        }
      ]

    data.forEach(data => {
      console.log(data.gfs); //Print the gfs value of every object in the array
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessed it by using 
`console.log(obj.data[3].gfs)`

I didn't take into account that the data key stored inside data inside obj(which I assigned)/